# No JIT Optimization

Tags: java, jit

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761515/java-multiplication-strange-behaviour) :

The code:

```java
class test
{
    public static void main(String abc[])
    {
        for( int k=1; k<=3; k++)
        {
            for( int N=1; N<=1_000_000_000; N=N*10)
            {
                long t1 = System.nanoTime();

                int j=1;
                for(int i=0; i<=N; i++)
                    j=j*i;

                long t2 = System.nanoTime() - t1;
                System.out.println("Time taken for "+ N + " : "+ t2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of above code:

```java
Time taken for 1 : 2160
Time taken for 10 : 1142
Time taken for 100 : 2651
Time taken for 1000 : 19453
Time taken for 10000 : 407754
Time taken for 100000 : 4648124
Time taken for 1000000 : 12859417
Time taken for 10000000 : 13706643
Time taken for 100000000 : 136928177
Time taken for 1000000000 : 1368847843
Time taken for 1 : 264
Time taken for 10 : 233
Time taken for 100 : 332
Time taken for 1000 : 1562
Time taken for 10000 : 17341
Time taken for 100000 : 136869
Time taken for 1000000 : 1366934
Time taken for 10000000 : 13689017
Time taken for 100000000 : 136887869
Time taken for 1000000000 : 1368178175
Time taken for 1 : 231
Time taken for 10 : 242
Time taken for 100 : 328
Time taken for 1000 : 1551
Time taken for 10000 : 13854
Time taken for 100000 : 136850
Time taken for 1000000 : 1366919
Time taken for 10000000 : 13692465
Time taken for 100000000 : 136833634
Time taken for 1000000000 : 1368862705
```

In the loop, even though the value of i starts from 0, indicating the product to be zero, there is no JIT Optimization. Why not ? 
In the link provided above, I had previously put the for loop in a method call, which the JIT was optimizing. Is putting the statements in a method facilitating in the optimization process ?

Comment: This doesn't feel like a very practical question. You're doing something useless - does the JIT optimization really matter to you for a *genuine* bit of code?

Comment: You are measuring the time in nanoseconds so it is fast enough. See the modified test for milliseconds here - http://ideone.com/Xq0xj1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In your previous question the JIT optimized away the complete code of the method `start` without any analysis as to what number happened to be present in the variables upon method return. This is because you chose to make your method `void`, giving the JIT a dead-easy clue that any values calculated will be discarded.
2. Contrasting your current example with the one from your previous question, there are no `void` methods called so naturally the optimization does not occur. Why there is not some *other* optimization which would help this completely different case is an unanswerable question. There is just no such optimization in the specefic JVM implementation, and the specific JVM invocation, with which you have tested your code.

Answer (score 2):

The loop itself does get jitted (as observed by the slightly lower running times on second and third execution), however eliminating the entire loop is - afaik - only done when the method itself is executed multiple times, because only then the JIT has sufficient runtime information to be sure it can actually eliminate it without consequence.

If I change your code, the loop is eliminated on the third invocation:

```
public class LoopJit2 {

    public static void main(String abc[]) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            loopMethod();
        }
    }

    private static void loopMethod() {
        for (int N = 1; N <= 1_000_000_000; N = N * 10) {
            long t1 = System.nanoTime();

            int j = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
                j = j * i;

            long t2 = System.nanoTime() - t1;
            System.out.println("Time taken for " + N + " : " + t2);
        }
    }
}
```

Time series:

```
Time taken for 1 : 1466
Time taken for 10 : 1467
Time taken for 100 : 2934
Time taken for 1000 : 20044
Time taken for 10000 : 201422
Time taken for 100000 : 1993200
Time taken for 1000000 : 4038223
Time taken for 10000000 : 11182357
Time taken for 100000000 : 111290192
Time taken for 1000000000 : 1038002176
Time taken for 1 : 1466
Time taken for 10 : 1467
Time taken for 100 : 2934
Time taken for 1000 : 20044
Time taken for 10000 : 10755
Time taken for 100000 : 124667
Time taken for 1000000 : 1010045
Time taken for 10000000 : 10201156
Time taken for 100000000 : 103184413
Time taken for 1000000000 : 1019723107
Time taken for 1 : 978
Time taken for 10 : 1467
Time taken for 100 : 1467
Time taken for 1000 : 1955
Time taken for 10000 : 978
Time taken for 100000 : 489
Time taken for 1000000 : 977
Time taken for 10000000 : 977
Time taken for 100000000 : 978
Time taken for 1000000000 : 978
```

Comment: Given your results it would appear that even the original code should have been optimized by on-stack-replacement. Maybe it just takes longer?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I also tried the original code with a larger interation count, my guess is that it first needs to run + jit the entire method at least once, and only then can it conclude it is safe to optimize it away.

Comment: I think implementing the JIT compiler/optimizer on per method basis is much more feasible than trying to do so in arbitrary blocks within methods. So this seems to be also an argument why you should try to break up functionality into smaller methods which get called by some other method. It allows the JIT to optimize each one independently.